# DRY-ify RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've spent most of an evening reading various articles and walkthroughs on RSpec. While I've learned a lot, I'm still a bit over my head with keeping things DRY and still useful. It's great that RSpec is so expressive, but it seems to make it difficult for beginners to write concise tests.

One thing I can see myself doing a lot of will be testing both sides of each edge case, as well as single or multiple valid values for a single variable. At the moment, I have the following for such a thing:

```
context "when physical address line 1 is too short" do
  before { @contact.physical_addr_line_1 = "1" }

  it { should_not be_valid }
  specify { @contact.save.should_not be_true }
end

context "when physical address line 1 is too long" do
  before { @contact.physical_addr_line_1 = "1"*111 }

  it { should_not be_valid }
  specify { @contact.save.should_not be_true }
end

context "when physical address line 1 is valid length" do
  before { @contact.physical_addr_line_1 = "11111" }

  it { should be_valid }
  specify { @contact.save.should be_true }
end
```

Is there a way of refactoring that to clean it up a bit? I want to add multiple more valid values in there (currently only checking based on length for that one), and perform the same set of tests on multiple other address line variables. Efficiency, readability, and maintainability are all important to me, so any suggestions on how to better approach this sort of test or any recommended reading would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dry it up a bit like this. Also make it more readable I think.

Define valid attributes once, in a before block:

```
before(:each) do
  @attr = #attributes hash
end

context "validations" do

  it "should not accept attribute that is too long" do
     long_string = "a" * unacceptable number
     Model.new(@attr.merge(attribute: long_string)).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should not accept attribute that is too short" do
     short_string = "a" * unacceptable number
     Model.new(@attr.merge(attribute: short_string)).should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Also, the shoulda gem is excellent. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda

It would allow to write tests like:

```
it {should ensure_length_of(:attribute).is_at_least(n).is_at_most(n)}
```

Comment: That shoulda gem is going to be a massive timesaver, thanks for that. The examples help a lot too.